# MVC Logging using Elmah, Log4Net and Health Monitoring

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, log4net, asp.net-mvc-4, elmah, health-monitoring

I recently found a 6 part article series on logging in MVC over at Darren's Blog (http://dotnetdarren.wordpress.com/).

It is a very good article on how to use Elmah, Log4Net, NLog, and Health Monitoring AND use a single UI to view and manage entries.

The article was written back in 2010, but I have successfully implemented it on an MVC 4 application that I am developing. The logging is working perfectly, but I do have an issue when trying to view entries in the combined UI.

I get the following error:

***"System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot resolve collation conflict for DISTINCT operation."***

If I comment out the configuration entry for Log4Net, I do not get the error any longer and I am able to see entries for Elmah and Health Monitoring. This error only occurs when trying to UNION in the entries from the Log4Net table.

Anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the code (VB.NET) where the problem occurs:

```
For Each providerName As String In logProviders.Keys
    Dim logList As IQueryable(Of LogEventModel) = GetProvider(providerName).GetByDateRangeAndType(pageIndex, pageSize, startDate, endDate, logLevel)
    ' Error occurs on this line below, only when Log4Net is in use.
    list = If((list Is Nothing), logList, list.Union(logList))
Next
```

Comment: probably a data type mismatch in the Union...maybe check what's different in the log4net table?

Comment: Update: Seems to be an issue between Health Monitoring and Log4Net. I can view Elmah & Health Monitoring OR Elmah & Log4Net, but I cannot do all 3 as it results in the error. Trying just Log4Net & Health Monitoring produces the same error. Strange....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem (with the same blog series)
If you haven't found a solution yet, here's what helped me :

[Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607560/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-and)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks Arnaud, I had found that article too. Unfortunately, this doesn't resolve it. The collation is the same on all text type columns.

Comment: Actually, I missed a table. The added table "aspnet_WebEvent_ErrorCodes" had the Name column and Level column set to a different collation. Once I used the alter script from the article, my issue resolved itself. Thanks again.