# "NVARCHAR(255) is null" brings collation conflict

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm having a temp procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 
#update_ListItemEntityNumberValueAndLocalizations(
    @modelPrefix NVARCHAR(255), 
    @definitionNeutralName NVARCHAR(255), 
    @listItemNeutralValue NVARCHAR(255),    
    @newNumberValue float,
    @listItemEnName NVARCHAR(255),
    @listItemDeName NVARCHAR(255))
```

In this procedure there is the following if statement:

```
if(@listItemEnName is not null)
```

And at this line I get the following error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the is
>   not operation.

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can avoid it?

UPDATE: Database collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

Why does a "is null" needs the collation?

Is there a way to cast the null or set the collation of the parameter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607560/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-and

Comment: I have found this also during my research but i do not realy know how this should help me... i dont have any table or column, just a parameter =/

Comment: @Dominik_Kirschenhofer Check rest of code for collation conflicts, the line number of the error is probably incorrct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an explicit collate clause

```
if(@listItemEnName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS is not null)
```

Or alternatively dependant upon what the stored procedure does switching the context to `USE tempdb;` then creating the temporary stored procedure and then switching the context back to your original database might work as below.

You are creating a temporary stored procedure so the parameter will be regarded as having the collation of `tempdb`. However `tempdb` must have a different collation from your user database.

As far as I can tell from experimentation when the stored procedure is first created it is bound to the database context in use (even if it is later `ALTER`-ed from a different database context).

. e.g. I am on a case sensitive collation but if I create the following procedure in a case insensitive database

```
CREATE PROC #Foo2 
AS
IF 'a' = 'A'
    PRINT 'Yes'
SELECT *
FROM sys.database_files
```

No matter what database I run it from it or if I alter it when `USE`-ing a different database it continues to print "Yes" and return information about the original database's files.

Comment: Seems to work, great thanks!
Could you also maybe explain why "in not null" needs to use the collation?

Comment: @DominikKirschenhofer - I can't think of any reason for this.

Comment: @SQLkiwi - Thanks! I did search connect but was looking for stuff about temporary stored procedures so didn't find that.