# Cannot-resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cannot resolve the collation conflict between “SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS” and “Latin1_General_CI_AS” in the equal to operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607560/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-and)

When I try to join two tables on the same column a.C1=b.C2 I get this message:

Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Can you tell me please is there any way to join them without changing the collations in tables?

```
SELECT * FROM
BIT_Dashboard.dse.Solution a
INNER JOIN
Leistungsportfolio.dbo.EBFHB_Jobliste b
ON a.Solution_NAM = b.SolutionName
WHERE a.Solution_NAM COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = b.SolutionName COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Error Msg: "Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation."

Comment: please look at my update

Answer (score 3):

error was in the ON clause (ON condition on the mentioned post)

corrent is:

```
SELECT * FROM 
BIT_Dashboard.dse.Solution a 
INNER JOIN
Leistungsportfolio.dbo.EBFHB_Jobliste b
ON 
a.Solution_NAM COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = b.SolutionName COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```