# SQL Collation conflict after database restore

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012, collation

I restored a site and database onto another machine, but cannot run the application because I am getting this error:

`InnerException message: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.`

Both machines are running MS SQL Server 2012 Standard edition and even the same minor version. I saw the other posts on this error, but could not find any tables or columns as Latin1_General_CI_AS. The database properties shows that the collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. Any ideas on ow to fix this?

Comment: What is the Server Collation? (Properties / General in SSMS)

Comment: See this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607560/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-and

Comment: @SqlACID, server collation is Latin1_General_CI_AS! I think you are on to something, please post an answer and I will accept. Good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the database servers collation and that worked. Apparently, temp tables were being populated by a stored procedure and choking since the database and the server were different collation.