# Collation Error Executing Stored Procedure From Java

Tags: java, sql-server-2012

I am trying to execute a Stored Procedure in SQL Server 2012 using the jTDS Driver version 1.3.1.  The stored procedure that I am executing runs find when executed from the management studio, but I get the following error when trying to executed it from my Java app.

java.sql.SQLException: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

I have hit a dead end as far as where to go next.  Has anyone experienced this before, or know what the cause is?  Thanks!

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607560/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-and

And maybe this one: http://samsudeenb.blogspot.com/2007/01/changing-database-collation.html

Comment: Thanks, @PawełGłowacz.  I am not sure that it is a collation issue with the tables because I can execute the SP outside of Java without getting the collate error.  I saw someone mention about upgrading the jtds driver for a similar issue they were having in the first thread.  I will try going up or down a version and see if it has any impact.  Thanks