# Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI" unified on code level

Tags: c#, sql

Ive got a question about Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI" and "Latin1_General_CI_AI", now I know it can be set in sql using COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI, but I have an app that connects to different Dbs and not all are throwing that exception. Is there a way to support this on code level?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/1607623/4848251

Comment: Using `COLLATE` in SQL *is* the code level. There is no flag, connection string setting or magic spell that will resolve collation conflicts in any other way. If not all apps are throwing the exception, then some are simply not issuing queries that run into collation conflicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not ideal but just include where the data joins in your script:

```
collate database_default
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any way to resolve this from the application code.

From the SQL Server side of things the best solution if possible is to have matching collations on all the different servers you connect to(beware of breaking other apps that rely on a specific collation)
If you don't have that level of control over your servers, second best would be to use the COLLATE command.

When your app connects to the database, you are comparing two columns that are stored using different collations.