# I get error SQL Msg 4104

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Using this code:

```
UPDATE MyBase.dbo.Inventory
SET Inventory.BarCode= Table1.Barcode
FROM Market.dbo.Table1, MyBase.dbo.Inventory
WHERE Table1.Barcode=Inventory.BarCode
```

I'm getting error message:Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "Table1.Barcode" could not be bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE t2 
SET t2.BarCode= t1.Barcode 
FROM Market.dbo.Table1 t1
join
 MyBase.dbo.Inventory t2 on t1.Barcode collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AS=t2.BarCode collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AS
```

issue is ,due to you are not qualifying it with DBname and you might not be in same database,also use aliases to make it more readable..

Also check below link all answer's for more on collations..

[Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607560/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-and)

Comment: It should be on,i added it

Comment: Now i get error: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AS" and "Greek_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Comment: try using collate `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AS`

Comment: @DiH:see updated answer,also can you post table schema of tables involved

Comment: How will i do this? i didnt do it again. Thank you for answers!

Comment: What if i want to update another table with checking barcode? UPDATE Customers 
SET Customer.Name = Table1.Name 
FROM Market.dbo.Table1 
join
MyBase.dbo.Customers  where  Table1.Barcode= inventory.BarCode collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AS

Answer (score 3):

You should use explicit joins for this, and give your tables proper aliases:

```
UPDATE I
SET I.BarCode = T.Barcode 
FROM MyBase.dbo.Inventory I
INNER JOIN Market.dbo.Table1 T
    ON I.BarCode = T.Barcode;
```