# collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" in the equal to operation

Tags: sql, inner-join, collation

This is my code

```
    SELECT  
                 CASE j.ANALYSIS  
                       WHEN  'INSTALL'  THEN 'ProtectedProperty'   
                       WHEN  'REMOVAL' THEN 'UnProtectedProperty'  
                 END   AS  label ,  
                       Count(P.PROPERTYREF) AS value   
                 FROM                                                   
                       properties AS p   WITH (NOLOCK)                                      
                 INNER JOIN           
                       jobs AS j  WITH (NOLOCK)
                 ON 
                       j.PROPERTYREF = p.PROPERTYREF          
                 INNER JOIN                                      
                       LIVE_PROPS AS lp   WITH (NOLOCK)           
                 ON  
                       j.PROPERTYREF =lp.PROPERTYREF                   
                 WHERE              
                       j.Completed BETWEEN @dtmStartTime AND @dtmEndTime                  
                 AND             
                       p.OFFICE In (Select OfficeId FROM tempTbl)
```

Got an error like
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Comment: try to convert any `varchar` type to `nvarchar`, such as `ON cast(col as nvarchar) = cast (colb as nvarchar)`

Comment: Typical symptoms of poor table design. If you think you have to add cast/collate to your query, you should take another look at you table design and consider changes!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL\_Latin1\_General\_CP1\_CI\_AS" and "Latin1\_General\_CI\_AS" in the equal to operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607560/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-and)

Comment: @LONG Mar - try to convert any varchar type to nvarchar,  was my case. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The collation is different between two of your columns. Add `COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS` after the offending equal to operation.

For example, if the problem was the LIVE_PROPS table:

```
INNER JOIN LIVE_PROPS AS lp WITH (NOLOCK)
     ON j.POPERTYREF = lp.PROPERTYREF COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Comment: And just forget about the original problem, poor db design.

Comment: depends on if you have control of the column.  i am sourcing from an upstream db and can collate to align with the edw collation