# Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operations

Tags: sql

This is my sql query

```
DELETE FROM [Prospects].[dbo].[P1]
WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(DomainName)) IN
    (SELECT RIGHT(UserEmail, LEN(UserEmail) - CHARINDEX('@', UserEmail)) UserEmail
     FROM   [Recruiter].[dbo].[tblSystemUser])
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Seems like you need to work on you db design... Consistent collation usage is the trick!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL\_Latin1\_General\_CP1\_CI\_AS" and "Latin1\_General\_CI\_AS" in the equal to operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607560/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-and)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add

```
COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

to the end of your query to convert it and fix the error, however this will take a performance hit.

As jarlh has suggested, changing the collation of the databases to be the same is the actual fix.

Comment: *changing the collation of the databases* sounds easy but is a really complex challenge. indexes, constraints, keys are depending on this... And it can lead into deepest troubles, if your server's default is different. This default is the default within your `tempdb`. When you use a `#table` and you try to join on a varchar column this would break with mysterious messages...

Comment: @Shnugo He has basically the same collation though just the SQL vs general versions... so shouldn't really break anything... And I was recommending he change the non-standard one to be the same as the server default, which will solve more problems than it creates probably. Only difference would be slight sort-order difference and unicode handling

Comment: I did not write about *wrong or changed results* but about *non-running code, which was perfectly running before*. I once had to change the collation of a database, which was a real pain in the neck. After this suddenly a bunch of stored procedures threw errors (something like *cannot resolve the collation conflict*). The reason where `ORDER BY` and `JOIN` operations on string columns in temp tables. We returned to the original collation after a while, which was again a pain in the neck :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT to your query :

```
DELETE FROM [Prospects].[dbo].[P1]
WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(DomainName)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT IN
(SELECT RIGHT(UserEmail, LEN(UserEmail) - CHARINDEX('@', UserEmail)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT UserEmail
 FROM   [Recruiter].[dbo].[tblSystemUser])
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it's

```
    DELETE FROM [Prospects].[dbo].[P1]
    WHERE RTRIM(LTRIM(DomainName)) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT IN
        (SELECT RIGHT(UserEmail, LEN(UserEmail) - CHARINDEX('@', UserEmail)) UserEmail
         FROM   [Recruiter].[dbo].[tblSystemUser

])
```