# Getting error in SQL Server "collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation."

Tags: sql-server

I have to take the store procedure from the server and go for creating in my local but that causes this error:

```
"Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AI" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation."
```

I have no idea why I am getting this error. I have followed many links and also tried to change all database collation but that is also getting an error. How can I fix this issue?

This is my store procedure =>

```
 DECLARE @Specialities nvarchar(max)

  INSERT INTO Feed // here i am getting error in sql server 
        (
            FId,         // here i am show datatype int
            SpecialityId,   // int
            IsTagged,       // bit
            InsertBy        // int
        )
    SELECT @CaseId,
           CategoryId,
           1,
           @UserId
    FROM Categories WHERE Category IN (SELECT items FROM Split(@Specialities,';'))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL\_Latin1\_General\_CP1\_CI\_AS" and "Latin1\_General\_CI\_AS" in the equal to operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607560/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-and)

Comment: @InnovaITveSolutions i know there are many users asking this question but i have also see those links but i don't want any solution then after i am posting this post.

Comment: As a quick fix; paste the select statement (without parameters) in a SQL Server View. SQL Server then automaticly adds the collation to the select statement. Look at the result and paste it back.

Comment: @coderwill the solution is to avoid mixing up collations. What is `Split` and what does it return? Is it a UDF? SQLCLR function? What attributes were used to create it?  Why are you using a CSV in the first place instead of, eg, a table variable?

Comment: The error complains about an `equal to` operation. There is no such operation in thw query you posted, which probably means that `Split` is a UDF that uses equality checks. Are you using one of the [string splitting echniques described by Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) perhaps? Does it use `varchar` parameters, or `varchar` instead of `nvarchar` conversions? For example, in the XML technique you need to read the string as `nvarchar` elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `COLLATE` to your subquery. Try both `Latin1_General_CI_AI` and `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

```
 DECLARE @Specialities nvarchar(max)

 INSERT INTO Feed // here i am getting error in sql server 
        (
            FId,         // here i am show datatype int
            SpecialityId,   // int
            IsTagged,       // bit
            InsertBy        // int
        )
    SELECT @CaseId,
           CategoryId,
           1,
           @UserId
    FROM Categories WHERE Category collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS IN (SELECT items FROM Split(@Specialities,';'))
```