# SQL Server collate error between 2 databases

Tags: sql-server, collation

I have had to take an existing stored procedure and amend it so that one of the tables now comes from a different database. The databases have been set up with different collate sequences.

Here's my code so far:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_GetContactDetails]            
    @SMID varchar(100) = ''            
AS                
BEGIN          
    SET NOCOUNT ON;    

    SELECT DISTINCT 
        a.StaffID as StaffID, a.FirstName as FirstName, 
        a.SurName as SurName, a.FirstName + ' ' + a.SurName as StaffName,        
        a.JobTitle as [Job Title],
        d.Dept as [Dept], a.Location as [Location], a.LocationID as [LocationID],
        ISNULL(b.Mobile, '') as [Mobile],        
        ISNULL(b.DirectFaxNo, '') as DirectFaxNo,    
        CAST(ISNULL(SP.[Profile_Description], '') AS VARCHAR(8000)) as [Profile],          
        DirectTel = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 siteTelephone 
                            FROM [Directory].dbo.Location o 
                            WHERE o.siteID = sit.SiteID), ''),
        OfficeFax = ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 SiteFax 
                            FROM [Directory].dbo.Location o 
                            WHERE o.siteID = sit.SiteID), ''),
        ISNULL(a.EmailAddress,'') as Email,        
        C.Designation as Designation,  JobID = ' '         
INTO 
    #contacts 
FROM
    Contact_Details c 
LEFT JOIN
    [Directory].dbo.ExtraDetails b ON C.Staffid collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = b.Staffid,            
    (SELECT 
         s.locationid , s.StaffID,          
         dbo.FUN_GetOfficeID(s.LocationID) as officeid             
     FROM 
         [Directory].dbo.vwStaff s) as OfficeTable,          
    [Directory].dbo.vwStaff a         
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [Directory].dbo.SiteLocation sit ON a.LocationID collate    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = sit.LocationID         
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.Staff_Profile SP ON a.Staffid collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = SP.Staff_Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    [Directory].dbo.department d ON a.DeptID collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = d.DeptID
WHERE 
    OfficeTable.StaffID = a.StaffID            
    AND a.Staffid = c.Staffid               
    AND
```

I keep getting the following error, but I don't know what else needs the collate statement.

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
>   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1607725/2224701

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. And you should **most definitely** not mix ANSI JOIN's with the deprecated style. And I'd recommend to be **consistent** with the naming - either use `LEFT JOIN`, or use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` - but not both - pick one and stick to it!

Comment: Yeah, I know. I just inherited the original code from someone else This was an SQL Server 2000 SP Originally, I slowly converting it.

Comment: Your query is incomplete... there is an `AND` at the bottom. What's the entire query?

Comment: @scsimon good point. I thought I'd pasted the whole code. However, I've managed to solve the issue. In the code above on the where clause I also had to place the 'Collate' on the left of that. It was the fact that the error was stating Line 1 that was throwing me.