# Collation conflict between different database collation in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, collation, linked-server

I have two different servers:

**Server 1**: It has database `DB1` with the `collation` `Latin1_General_CI_AS`

**Server 2**: has `DB2` with the `collation` `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

I come up with the scenario where i need to backup and restore `DB1` from `server 1` to `server 2`.

When I run a simple select statement through the `linked server`, I end up with an error by saying `Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use : COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT on both sides of condition for character columns. Example below.

```
    select * from es
    inner join es e2
    on es.year COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = e2.year COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple workaround is to restore DB1 on server1 to a new database "DB2"; then you can try to change the collation of DB2 to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, and finally try to restore DB2 to server2.

I also found another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607560/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-and) which might be helpful.

Comment: Creating DB2 is important to keep the origin DB unchanged to avoid any DB issues.