# Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing column metadata

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have an existing database in SQL Server 2008 that we worked with in our project (JAVA) and now we want to recreate the project using spring boot but I have a problem :

I have a relation between Producer and Field classes, and also I set a foreign key in Field table.

Producer class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "WL_RT_LOCATION_REF")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Producer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "LOCATION_KEY")
    private BigDecimal locationKey;

    @Column(name = "LOCA_FIELD")
    private String locationField;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "producer", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Field> fields;
    ....getters and setters
}
```

Field class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "WL_RT_SITE_REF")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Field implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SITE_KEY")
    private BigDecimal siteKey;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="LOCATION_KEY", referencedColumnName = "LOCATION_KEY", nullable=false)
    private Producer producer;

    @Column(name = "WELL")
    private String fieldName;

    @Column(name = "DESCR")
    private String descr;
    ....getters and setters
}
```

When I run the project I get this error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing column metadata: DEMODB.dbo.WL_RT_SITE_REF
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at com.welllynxserverside.WelllynxserversideApplication.main(WelllynxserversideApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing column metadata: DEMODB.dbo.WL_RT_SITE_REF
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error accessing column metadata: DEMODB.dbo.WL_RT_SITE_REF
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.convertSQLException(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getForeignKeys(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:849) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.foreignKeys(TableInformationImpl.java:97) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.TableInformationImpl.getForeignKeys(TableInformationImpl.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.checkForExistingForeignKey(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:471) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.applyForeignKeys(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:423) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:114) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:939) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "French_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.getResultSetForForeignKeyInformation(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:1003) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.getImportedKeys(SQLServerDatabaseMetaData.java:875) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getForeignKeys(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:798) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
```

Please can any one help me ??

Comment: Have you considered letting JOOQ build your repositories and entities for you? Very likely will solve this problem within 5 minutes of effort.

Comment: no how can I do that ?? ( I am using Intellij Idea )

Comment: Ah...even easier. This: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-persistence-mapping-import-dialogs.html and enable JPA annotations.

Comment: In your exception is written about "Error accessing column metadata" but only the table name is written and no column name and no other useful info from exception. Do you have DEMODB.dbo.WL_RT_SITE_REF table in your DB? Maybe problem in your schema name or hibernate-properties or user permissions on this table? Can you show us hibernate-properties from your project (without usernames, passwords and another private information)?

Comment: @AnatolySamoylenko  yes I WL_RT_SITE_REF table in my DB, this is the content of **application.properties** : 

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=DEMODB
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans=false

Comment: @Badr Eddine Ztaoui application.properties looks normal. Can you add full stack-trace of exception in your question? Lines after "Error accessing column metadata: DEMODB.dbo.WL_RT_SITE_REF". I think the answer is in that lines.

Comment: @AnatolySamoylenko can you check out please I've added the full stack-trace of exception

Comment: @Badr Eddine Ztaoui     Problem is 'Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "French_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.'     I know little about this error. Try to look [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/590) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607560/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-and).