# Cannot Resolve Collation Conflict in Join Statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following join, that spits out this error

> "Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_BIN" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

I tried editing by adding:

```
ns.dw_item_location COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN AS dil
```

as well as

```
ns.dw_item_location COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS dil
```

and didn't resolve this error. I also tried

```
IR.ItemNo COLLATE_Latin1_General_BIN as ItemNo
```

earlier in the SQL statement and still no resolution.

```
left join ns.dw_item_location dil on dil.znumber = IR.ItemNo
```

The expected outcome should resolve this error by correcting the correlation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL\_Latin1\_General\_CP1\_CI\_AS" and "Latin1\_General\_CI\_AS" in the equal to operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607560/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-and)

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the collate in the wrong place. You should put it immediately after the column name inside the equals clause

```
left join ns.dw_item_location dil on dil.znumber collate database_default = IR.ItemNo
```

You will notice I used database_default meaning "whatever the current database uses" which is usually simpler if you have a conflict between "this" database and "another" database.