# Multiple Inner Join is not working for SQL Statement in MS Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server

concept of multiple inner join:

```
from A inner join B on A.name = B.name

inner join C on A.name = C.name

inner join D on A.name = D.name

inner join D on A.meme = D.meme
```

error alert:

`[SqlServerODBC] (60) Response error: Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "Latin1_General_BIN" in the equal to operation., Statement(s) could not be prepared.,`.

Comment: You have a mismatch of two different collations in your table. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607560/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-and)

Answer (score 0):

Tables with a related column present in the query have different collations at the column level.  The binary collation is set at the column level.
One column has  `Latin1_General_BIN` collation and the other column has `Latin1_General_CI_AS` collation.

To find the collation of columns, below statement can be used.

```
SELECT
col.name, col.collation_name
FROM 
sys.columns col
WHERE
object_id = OBJECT_ID(<TableName>)
```

To resolve this issue, use the collation name after the column name in the query.

```
inner join C on A.name = C.name COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
```

**ADDED POINTS**

If your table name is `TABLENAME` , then add this name in **single quote** as shown below, to get the collation.

```
SELECT
col.name, col.collation_name
FROM 
sys.columns col
WHERE
object_id = OBJECT_ID('TABLENAME')
```

Don't make any other changes in the above code. Try this for all your tables and check the collation types.

It's generally a good idea to have a single, unique collation used throughout your database, don't use different collations within a single table or database. If your columns have different collation, then make it unique by altering the table column by using the following script.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTableName
  ALTER COLUMN YourColumnName
    VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, after adding this  COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, the values are wrong. What is this code represents?

Comment: @WingKuan : Did you checked the type of collations in each column in your table(s) using the query which I mentioned?

Comment: You need to update the table name only. no need to change the **FROM** clause. I have added an update in the answer.