# trying to use a IN in my WHERE clause with varchar but running into Collate Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, varchar

I have two tables in my database right now.

```
Table1
ID        Value1    VText2      VText3      
1         1XX1      text1       text1
2         2XX2      text2       text2
3         3XX3      text3       text3


Table2
ID        OtherValue
1         1XX1
2         2XX2
```

This is a much simplified version of my tables.In a nutshell Value1 in Table1 is varchar, and OtherValue in Table2 is a Varchar as well.

My goal is this:

```
SELECT * From TABLE1 where Value1 in (SELECT OtherValue from Table2)
```

When i execute this I'm running into this error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" in
>   the equal to operation.

```
Desired end result:
ID        Value1    VText2      VText3      
1         1XX1      text1       text1
2         2XX2      text2       text2
```

I believe this is happening because I'm using VARCHAR values with my "WHERE IN" clause. Is there a way to do this with varchars?

Comment: You have a mismatch of two different collations in your table. [CHECK THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1607623/4295763)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obviously happening because the collation is different in the two tables.

You can do the conversion manually.  It is unclear what you want, but something like this:

```
WHERE Value1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS IN (SELECT OtherValue from Table2)
```

Normally, strings in the same database would be expected to have the same collation.  However, it is possible to have different collations -- just so errors like this can pop up ;)